# Killing Launch Daemon

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

My app runs a launch daemon so the main app can be started synchronically with iTunes.
The daemon runs with no issues.

However, when I disable the daemon to start at login, the daemon is already launched and keeps opening the main app until the user restarts the computer and the daemon is shut down.

How can I terminate my daemon process? Because it's a process with no interface, the app is no `NSRunningApplication`.

---

### EDIT

Worthy to say, the application will have to be sandboxed.

Comment: Is it visible in Force-Quit window?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya No, it's background only

Comment: I would suggest you to give something to select it, like a dock icon or an Apple menu icon.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Hm. The idea of the daemon was really only to launch the main app if iTunes is launched. The user shouldn't see that another process is launched unless iTunes is. Or do you have another idea in mind?

Comment: I created an application just like Force-Quit, but it was able to show all process like, camera, blue tooth, wifi etc. I used apple menu to start and stop. that is what I asked you to do. and you will see just a small icon next to speaker, eject, wifi, bluetooth....

Comment: @AnoopVaidya I'm not sure what you mean. The main app of course has an interface. Just the daemon doesn't. That's exactly what I need, I need to list all processes, like camera, blue tooth, etc.

Comment: ohh. sorry for not understanding your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, by removing the helper app from the daemon services list, the app automatically gets killed.

---

### Code

```
- (void)setLaunchHelperAtLogin:(BOOL)launchHelperAtLogin {
    if (launchHelperAtLogin != self.launchHelperAtLogin) {
        // Creating helper app complete URL
        NSURL *bundleURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL];
        NSURL *url = [bundleURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:kHelperPath];

        // Registering helper app
        OSStatus status = LSRegisterURL((__bridge CFURLRef)url, true);
        if (status != noErr) {
            NSError *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:NSOSStatusErrorDomain code:status userInfo:nil];
            NSLog(@"%@", error);
        }

        // Setting login
        if (!SMLoginItemSetEnabled((CFStringRef)kHelperBundleIdentifier, launchHelperAtLogin)) {
            NSLog(@"SMLoginItemSetEnabled failed!");
        }
    }
}
```